# gnu.io.PortInUseException: Unknown Application?

Tags: serial-port, rxtx

```
void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
{
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
    if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(portIdentifier.getCurrentOwner());
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

        if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
            (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
        }
    }     
}
```

is giving

```
gnu.io.PortInUseException: Unknown Application
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.open(CommPortIdentifier.java:354)
```

i am using RXTX with Java in windows 7 home 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reboot the system / disable the port.
Actual problem is when the program runs port is opened and it didn't close after the program terminates.
it works.

Answer (score 16):

Check that /var/lock folder exist on your machine.

```
mkdir /var/lock
chmod go+rwx /var/lock
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem because the port *was* actually in use. A previous instance of javaw.exe appeared in the Windows task manager, it hogged the port.

The reason why that previous java process hung was a hardware issue: When plugging the USB-2-serial converter that I happened to use into a USB-2 port, all worked fine. When plugged into a USB-3 port, RXTX CommPortIdentifier code would hang, and then subsequent instances of Java received the PortInUseException.

Answer (score 0):

I used Process Explorer to find a process with the handle `\Device\PCISerial0` and closed the handle. If your com ports aren't on a PCI card, the name might be different.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 
Open Task Manager
under Eclipse (or your ide) find Java application. 
Right click on it -> End Task

Answer (score 0):

May be useful, I solved such problem by remove gateway from service and stop it , gateway is instance of SerialModemGateway.

`Service.getInstance().stopService();`
`Service.getInstance().removeGateway(gateway);`
`gateway.stopGateway();`