# Java + arduino not connecting

Tags: java, arduino, rxtx

I'm working on connecting a JavaFx application to arduino and have run into dozens of errors. There are very bad tutorials online for connecting these platforms. I am currently on a mac and have tried three different solutions to no avail. I'm trying to just get the following simple tutorial to work: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/control-an-arduino-from-java/240163864

I keep getting the following issue

```
RXTX Warning:  Removing stale lock file. /var/lock/LK.072.031.048
gnu.io.PortInUseException: Unknown Application
at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.open(CommPortIdentifier.java:354)
at com.musicPlayer.JML.SerialTest.initialize(SerialTest.java:53)
at com.musicPlayer.JML.SerialTest.main(SerialTest.java:143)
```

I have a /var/lock and have cleared the folder but it still doesn't work, I've tried giving it 777 permissions and go+rwx but nothing works. If you have any suggestions please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044758/gnu-io-portinuseexception-unknown-application help? (Specifically: Find out which program has the port open and close it, or reboot the system)

Comment: @immibis I'll try and see if that works. It's late where I am so I'll save that for tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer to this but do have two things to say:

- The stale lock file is just a warning
- Try using a different port.

Hope this helped. :)